# Has turbulence ever killed a passenger?

Tags: aviation-history, accidents, passenger, turbulence, accident-statistics

The question is on my mind, because many passengers think there is no need to wear the seatbelt when the seatbelt sign is not illuminated.

Comment: Related: [Do we have a unit to measure turbulence?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12117/3201) (which links to [this table](https://maps.avnwx.com/help/turb_desc.html)  of effects) and [How dangerous was the turbulence on this commercial flight?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23271/3201)

Answer (score 5):

The following is a [list of deadly turbulence accidents on jet airliners since 1980](http://www.airsafe.com/events/turb.htm).
Excluded are accidents involving jet airliners designed or built in the former Soviet Union.
For a more complete list see [aviation-safety.net](https://aviation-safety.net/database/events/dblist.php?Event=WXT).

- [10 May 1980, Indian Airlines B737-200, near Rampur Hat/India](https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/wiki.php?id=173225):
  The aircraft experienced severe en route turbulence. 2 of the 132 passengers were killed.
- [7 October 1981, NLM CityHopper F28-4000, Moerdijk/Netherlands](https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=19811006-0):
  Shortly after takeoff, the aircraft entered an area of severe thunderstorm activity. The aircraft apparently had a catastrophic in flight structural failure due to severe turbulence because it was seen to emerge from the clouds with one of its wings broken away. All 4 crew members and 13 passengers were killed.
- [16 August 1982, China Airlines B747, near Hong Kong](http://archive.is/XxwQ6):
  The aircraft encountered severe in flight turbulence. 2 (out of 292) passengers not wearing seatbelts were killed.
- [3 October 1990, Eastern Air Lines Flight 791, DC9-31, Florida/USA](https://www.planecrashwiki.com/flight/Eastern-Air-Lines-791-2550):
  The aircraft clear air turbulence at 31,000 feet (9450 m). 1 injured passenger died 3 weeks later.
- [5 September 1996, Air France B747-400, near Ouagadougou/Burkina Faso](http://www.bea.aero/docspa/1996/f-tf960905/pdf/f-tf960905.pdf):
  Severe turbulence associated with a weather front seriously injured 3 of the 206 passengers. 1 of the 3 passengers later died of injuries caused by an in flight entertainment screen.
- [28 December 1997, United Airlines Flight 826, B747-100, over Pacific Ocean near Japan](https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=19971228-0):
  The aircraft encountered severe turbulence during cruise about 2 hours after departing Japan. 1 of the 346 passengers was killed and 3 crew members sustained serious injuries.

Comment: I don't think the last one should count.  The question relates to pax killed by being rattled around the cabin. That was just the pilot flying stomping on the rudder in concert with aileron inputs, as if he was in a light aircraft, which is a really bad thing to do in a swept wing jet.  Vertical fins are not designed to withstand the bending from full rudder inputs above certain speeds, and in a swept wing jet with yaw dampers you don't need to actually touch the rudder pedals once airborne unless an engine quits.

Comment: @JohnK: You are right. I must have misunderstood my own question ;) I'll remove AA587.

Comment: Interesting tidbit: the second entry on the list involved the aircraft inadvertently flying _through a tornado_.